# Class Attribute value does not change

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and part of my excercise is to introduce betting into an already working code of Black Jack game. Now I have surprsing worked the solution out but the issue is after the first round is  finished, the value of the Pot(Player Pot) stays the same, ie the Pot of the Black jack player. If the player win or lose, I want the Pot to update accordingly in the below code it would be self.Bet . What am I  missing ? The main part of the code as below

```
 def lose(self):
    print(self.name, "loses.")
    print("Your pot is now ", self.loses)
    self.loses=self.Bet
    return self.Bet

def win(self):
    print(self.name, "wins.")
    print ("Congratulations you won ")
    print("Your Pot is now ", self.wins)
    self.wins=self.Bet
    return self.Bet
    

def push(self):
    print(self.name, "pushes.")
    
def Betting(self):
    bet=int(input("\n " + self.name + " How much would you like to bet : "))
    if bet <self.Bet:
        print("Your bet is", bet)
        self.loses = self.Bet - bet
        self.wins = self.Bet + bet
        
    else:
        print("You do not have enough funds to bet")
        
    return self.loses, self.wins
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `self.Bet` to the value that the player won/lost depending on the result (`self.wins`/`self.loses`) you do the other way around and set `self.wins`/`self.loses` to the value of `self.Bet`.

Change `self.loses=self.Bet` -> `self.Bet=self.loses` (although I would also recommend adding spaces around the `=` to follow Python conventions)